# Class instance not saving to HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a web app using forms authentication that shares messages between users based on the time they logged in. I use a class called `CurrentUser` that stores information on the current user. I need each visitor to have their own instance of this class, and I'm trying to place it in `HttpContext.Current.Items`. Here's my class:

```
public class CurrentUser
{
    public DateTime JoinRoomTime;

    public static CurrentUser Instance
    {
        get
        {
            IDictionary items = HttpContext.Current.Items;

            if (!items.Contains("TheInstance"))
            {
                items["TheInstance"] = new CurrentUser();
            }

            return items["TheInstance"] as CurrentUser;
        }
    }

    public CurrentUser()
    {
        JoinRoomTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    }
}
```

Every time I reference `CurrentUser.Instance.JoinRoomTime`, the constructor is called, resetting `JoinRoomTime`. Debugging, I find that `items["TheInstance"] = new CurrentUser()` is being called every reference made to `Instance`. Why is it not saving to `HttpContext.Current.Items`?

Comment: Why not just use Session? I have a feeling (not 100% sure) that HttpContext is only alive for the length of the request, not the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext.Current is scoped to a single HTTP request. Data associated with it does not persist between requests.

Answer (score 1):

> Every time I reference CurrentUser.Instance.JoinRoomTime, the constructor is called, resetting JoinRoomTime.

Meaning, reference in a **new** request? [`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) is per-request, it is the `HttpContext` for the *current request*. It is reinitialized when a new request is made.